# unsupportedcommand exception for JavascriptExecutor in Appium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm running my tests on Android browser where all the JS click was working fine till last week, but today it's throwing below exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError (/root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/root/appium/appium/1.16.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Appium version as 1.15.0 and selenium version as below.

```
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


Please suggest
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to parse a non JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the stack trace of your error and then checking the source code of the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) library (which you are using)
see here: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js#L81

It's clear that you get this error because the string you pass to `parse` function has the first character different than `{` or `[`, which means it's not a JSON format.

And also from the error I can see that the first token (or the character) of the input is `a` and a JSON cannot start with this token.

I think you have to put a log before `parse` function, to see what are you passing and correct the input.

Comment: i'm using Javascript only to click the element JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); still the error throwing